# Tkinter: disable text widget content auto resize (newline), when user resize window

Tags: python, tkinter, text, resize

**Advice**: i'm working on Windows 8.1, with Python and Tkinter at last version; i wrote `from tkinter import *` to post less code here, i know that it is a bad practice, use for example  `import tkinter as tk` instead.

I'm coding my first text editor, and i have a problem when i resize the main windows. When i run the program it display on screen a window with dimension 750x500 pixel. So far, all ok, i can write text without problem (note that menu_bar and other features are work-in progress, but we dont care about them). Problem is with Text widget when user tries to resize window with cursor. The content of the text practically adapts to the size of the window (the length of each string is reduced or increased based on the width of the window). But i don't want that this happen. I want that Text widget changes his width automatically in base of window size, but the content mustn't be adapted. I hope that you understand my question, if not, i will try to explain better.
I have searched on online reference if there's a parameter to set this option, but i haven't found anything.

How to solve the problems concerning the Text widget and resizing the window?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry("750x500")

content_text = Text(root, wrap=WORD, bg="grey25", undo=True, cursor="",
                    insertbackground="red", foreground="white", font="courier 12")
content_text.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

scroll_bar = Scrollbar(content_text)
content_text.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set, selectbackground="dodgerblue")
scroll_bar.configure(command=content_text.yview)
scroll_bar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please reduce this code down to a [mcve]. For example, unless part of the problem involves cutting and pasting text, we don't need the `cut`,`copy`, `paste`, `undo`, and `redo` functions. We don't need the menubar either.

Comment: Ok, now i'm doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want. If you have wrapping turned on, text will always wrap at the edge of the window. When you change the width of the window, the text will re-wrap to the new width. There is no configuration option to tell the widget to wrap at any other place.